# Javascript: Change multiple Element styles by ID

Tags: javascript, css

I'm actually working on a darkmode and have a problem to change the css of more than one element.

JS code:

```
      var elem = document.getElementById('fonts');
      for(var i=0; i<elem.length; i++){
        elem[i].style.color="#FFFFFF";
        console.log(elem[i]);
      }
```

But nothing changes.. i think i need to do it with the loop because i got more elements with the id "fonts". If i do it without the loop, than will only change the first one.

The console dont give an error or anything.. did i something wrong?

Comment: *id* is for unique element, you can use *class* instead, please include the HTML in the question.

Comment: Are you still have problem? @DirtyyyDan

Comment: @Danial no, its done

Answer (score 2):

Well you are doing it the wrong way, firstly you can use same `id` for multiple elements instead you have to use a class

So check this out

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var elem = document.querySelectorAll('.fonts');

  for(var i=0; i<elem.length; i++){
    elem[i].style.color = "#00aeff";
    console.log(elem[i]);
  }
});
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

```html
<h1 class="fonts">Heading1</h1>
<p class="fonts">Paragraph</p>
<span class="fonts">Span</span>
<div class="fonts">Div</div>

<button id="btn">Change</button>
```

And the CSS and button are not necessary it's just for example, you use `querySelectorAll` to select all the elements with same class or whatever and then run a `for loop` on those elements

Answer (score 0):

you can only use the `<div id="fonts">` once. so if you have it multiple times in your html your code won't work..

1. change id's to classes
2. try your code try using the HTML DOM "querySelector" instead of "getElementById".

for an id use this syntax

```
  var elem = document.querySelector("#fonts");
```

for a class use this syntax

```
var elem = document.querySelector(".fonts");
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use the `for...of` statement to simplified the code and increase more readability

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let elem = document.querySelectorAll('.fonts');

  for (let font of elem) {
    font.style.color = "#00aeff";
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="fonts">Heading1</h1>
<p class="fonts">Paragraph</p>
<span class="fonts">Span</span>
<div class="fonts">Div</div>

<button id="btn">Change</button>
```